# WCF/Windows Service not working

Tags: wcf, dll, windows-services

I'm trying to create a windows service along with WCF.  We don't want to use IIS to handle the proxying of the service.  I've gotten the service registered and started.  I created a simple console application to call the service, but it times out.

I have a .NET DLL containing functions that call a locally running application to create an alarm record.  I created a forms application that uses AlarmLib.dll and it is able to make the call and insert the alarm record.

It appears to be a permissions issue.  I get the following exception:

```
> Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:
> Could not co nnect to http://localhost:8000/ServiceModel/service. TCP
> error code 10061: No co nnection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:
> 8000.  ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote
> server --->  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could
> be made because the tar get machine actively refused it
> 127.0.0.1:8000
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
> SocketAddre ss socketAddress)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)    at
> System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
> Sock et s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
> ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout,
> Exception& exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext&
> context)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStre
> am()    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I ran VS2010 as an administrator.  Any other settings for the service that I can modify?

Thanks,
John

**Windows service code:**

```
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using AlarmLib;

namespace Test.ServiceModel

.WindowsServices {



        // 

Define a service contract.
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://ServiceModel.WindowsServices")]
    public interface IAlarmLib {
        [OperationContract]
        bool CreateNoDataAlarm(string well, string run, string record, string description, string selectedVariable);
    }

    // Implement the IAlarmLib service contract in a service class.
    public class AlarmLibService : IAlarmLib {
        // Implement the IAlarmLib methods.


    public bool CreateNoDataAlarm(string well, string run, string record, string description, string sel

ectedVariable) {
            AlarmUserConfiguration newalarm = new AlarmUserConfiguration();

            // The Machine name should be the machine which is running the client application
            // and which calls the webservice. This should not be the name of machine hosting

        // webservice.
        newalarm.MachineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
        newalarm.AlarmType = AlarmTypes.NoData;
        newalarm.TimeInSeconds = 30;
        DateTime CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
        newalarm.Name = "NoDataAlarm " + CreationTime.ToString();
        PrimaryKey key = new PrimaryKey();
        key.Well = "Well ID 1";
        key.Run = "1600";
        key.Record = "DGR";
        key.Desc = "Realtime";
        key.SelectedVariable = "Gamma Ray A";
        newalarm.PrimaryKeys = key;

        // Add any of the following activities.
        /*"All"
        "Trip Out"
        "Trip In"
        "Circulating"
        "Drilling On Bottom"
        "Drilling Off Bottom"*/

        newalarm.TDActivities.Add("Drilling On Bottom");

        bool bStatus = AlarmUtilities.AddNewAlarm(newalarm, "-Local-");
        return bStatus;
    }
}

public class AlarmLibWindowsService : ServiceBase {
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
    public AlarmLibWindowsService() {
        // Name the Windows Service
        ServiceName = "AlarmLibWS";
    }

    public static void Main() {
        ServiceBase.Run(new AlarmLibWindowsService());
    }

    // Start the Windows service.
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
        if (serviceHost != null) {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }

        // Create a ServiceHost for the AlarmLibService type and 
        // provide the base address.
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(AlarmLibService));

        // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
        // listening for messages.
        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop() {
        if (serviceHost != null) {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
}

// Provide the ProjectInstaller class which allows 
// the service to be installed by the Installutil.exe tool
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer {
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;

    public ProjectInstaller() {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();


          process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            service = new ServiceInstaller();
            service.ServiceName = "AlarmLibWS";
            Installers.Add(process);
            Installers.Add(service);
        }
    }
}
```

**App.config:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <!-- This section is optional with the new configuration model
           introduced in .NET Framework 4. -->
      <service name="ServiceModel.WindowsServices.AlarmLibService" behaviorConfiguration="AlarmLibServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModel/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModel/service  -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="ServiceModel.WindowsServices.IAlarmLib" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModel/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="AlarmLibServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Console app:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestAlarmLibConsoleApp {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            ServiceReference1.AlarmLibClient client = new ServiceReference1.AlarmLibClient();
            bool result = client.CreateNoDataAlarm("Well ID 1", "1100", "DGR", "Realtime", "Gamma Ray A");
            Console.WriteLine("result = " + bool.TrueString);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the code in forms app that works:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AlarmLib;

namespace TestCallingAlarmLib {
    static class Program {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            bool result = CreateNoDataAlarm();

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        static bool CreateNoDataAlarm() {
            AlarmUserConfiguration newalarm = new AlarmUserConfiguration();

            // The Machine name should be the machine which is running the client application
            // and which calls the webservice. This should not be the name of machine hosting
            // webservice.
            newalarm.MachineName = System.Environment.MachineName;
            newalarm.AlarmType = AlarmTypes.NoData;
            newalarm.TimeInSeconds = 30;
            DateTime CreationTime = DateTime.Now;
            newalarm.Name = "NoDataAlarm " + CreationTime.ToString();
            PrimaryKey key = new PrimaryKey();
            key.Well = "Well ID 1";
            key.Run = "1100";
            key.Record = "DGR";
            key.Desc = "Realtime";
            key.SelectedVariable = "Gamma Ray A";
            newalarm.PrimaryKeys = key;

            // Add any of the following activities.
            /*"All"
            "Trip Out"
            "Trip In"
            "Circulating"
            "Drilling On Bottom"
            "Drilling Off Bottom"*/

            newalarm.TDActivities.Add("Drilling On Bottom");

            bool bStatus = AlarmUtilities.AddNewAlarm(newalarm, "-Local-");
            return bStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the basics of your code in the Windows service??

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?  What happens if you break into the code in the timed-out state?

Comment: How would I add the different projects to my solution, so I can debug into the code and see where it's failing?  Do I need to include the AlarmLib.dll project?

Comment: Please reassure me that the namespaces of Halliburton and web service name which indicates some monitoring alarm are humor, otherwise I'm going to start looking for the next oil rig failure.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Client Access Policy, make sure you have the ports opened up on the server and double check your firewall.  Every single time I get this error it's related to one of those.